# Listening for Google Voice SMS

Tags: android, google-voice

I have been trying to write a simple Android app that listens for broadcasts with the filter "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED". This works for when the device receives an SMS with the default messaging application, but SMSes received through the Google Voice app don't broadcast this intent. Also, Google Voice doesn't have an option for forwarding messages to the default messaging app while also posting notifications from the voice app (which is superior, in my opinion).

Is there a different kind of intent I should be listening for? Has anyone else been successful in intercepting Google Voice messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always query https://clients4.google.com/voice/request/unread I guess. It's messy, but you'll know when there's a new message, I guess.

Google Voice is annoying because it has no api and the interface is practically non-functional, so that's probably the best you'll get.